# How to use external jar in phonegap application?

Tags: cordova, jar

I was created the jar file consist of java code. I want to use this jar into my phonegap application. I was already added this JAR to libs folder of my working copy.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a plugin for that.

You'll need a class that extends the CordovaPlugin class. In this class you will add code to call code from your jar in the execute method.

And you'll have to also create a javascript file to be able to call the java code from javascript.

You can follow the following guides or have a look at the code of phonegap api plugins.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today while trying to setup an interaction with an SMTP server.  In your plugin.xml file under the platform tag, add the jar files as a source-file, and set the target directory to libs/

For example:

```
<source-file src="src/android/mail.jar" target-dir="libs/" />
<source-file src="src/android/additionnal.jar" target-dir="libs/" />
<source-file src="src/android/activation.jar" target-dir="libs/" />
<source-file src="src/android/MyPlugin.java" target-dir="src/targetpath/to/plugin/here" />
```